# IAM for Google Cloud DNS: Restrict permissions to one managedZone?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to restrict DNS Administrator role permissions to only one ManagedZone, say the resource `//dns.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/managedZones/example-com`

When I go to the troubleshooter, It says that's not a valid resource name. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud DNS does not support assigning IAM policies to managed zones.

At this time you can only assign an IAM policy at the project/folder/org resource level which grants rights to all managed zones within the resource (project/folder/org).